# Using limits to determine asymptotic bound

Tags: asymptotics

By using limits, show that log n! ∈ Θ(n logn).

Using Stirling's approximation for n! I get the limit:
$$\lim_{n \to ∞} \frac{log({\sqrt{2πn}}*(\frac{n}{e})^n)}{nlogn} = constant > 0$$

When I break this down separately:
$$\lim_{n \to ∞} \frac{\sqrt{2πn}}{n^n} * \lim_{n \to ∞} (\frac{n}{e})^n = constant > 0$$

To me, the left limit approaches 0 and the right limit approaches infinity. Can I not rewrite the limit like this? Or do I need to use L'Hopistal's rule? Because I don't understand how I would do that here.

Comment: You dropped the logarithms and created an undefined limit. This leads you nowhere.

Comment: @YvesDaoust O.o I was too quick and reading the question and I didn't realize that. In addition to your observation, the denominator of the first limit in the product is weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some algebra mistake but, in general, you are right that you cannot always rewrite a limit of products as the products of limits.
Let $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ be two functions. Then
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)g(n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)$$
only holds if  $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)$  exist and are either both finite, or one is infinite and the other is not $0$.

To handle the original limit without using L'Hôpital's rule:
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{\log n!}{n \log n} &=
\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{\log (\sqrt{2\pi n} \cdot (n/e)^n )}{n \log n}\\
& =\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{\log \sqrt{2\pi n}}{n \log n} 
+ \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{\log  (n/e)^n }{n \log n} \\
&=0 + \lim_{n \to \infty}   \frac{n \log n }{n \log n} -  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n \log e}{n \log n} 
=1 - 0 = 1.
\end{align*}
$$

Therefore $\log n! \sim n \log n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log\left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\dfrac ne\right)^n\right)=\log\sqrt{2\pi}+\frac12\log n +n\log n-n.$$

Clearly, this expression is dominated by the term $n\log n$ and your limit is $1$.

Comment: This is a bit nitpicky, but since we don't know the base of the $\log$ you could replace the last term with $-n \log e$ to cover all bases (pun intended).

Comment: @Steven: in calculus, $\log$ is usually natural.

Comment: Everywhere, ln is always the natural logarithm. Should be used unless it doesn't matter.

Comment: @gnasher729: for some reason, on Mathematics 99% of the posts use $\log$.

Comment: Well, this is computer science, not mathematics.

Comment: @gnasher729: you are right to remind us that the natural logarithm is obtained with `log()`, and the decimal logarithm with `log10()` under POSIX [respectively `ALOG/ALOG10` in FORTRAN].

Answer (score 0):

You broke this down, but in a very unpractical way.

$\log {(n/e)^n} = n \log (n /e) = n (\log n - 1)$ is much more helpful.